# How do I create a bar graph using a FOR-loop using JavaScript, CSS and HTML only?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart using JavaScript and HTML but the chart is not displaying correctly. It doesn't look like a bar chart. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The only thing that displays are the values. How can I make it work without using an external JS file (reusing someone else's code)? This is for an intro to JavaScript course and I have to use a div instead of a canvas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bar Chart</title>

    <style>
        #chart {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            background-color: aliceblue;
            display: block;
        }
        .bar{
            background: green;
        }
        .exceed{
            background: blueviolet;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body> 
        <div id="chart"></div>

<script>
// and variables

const DPOINTS = 400;
const MAX = 300;
const EXCEED = 0.8;
let c;
let value;

let chart = document.getElementById("chart");

for (let c =0; c <= DPOINTS; c++){

 value = Math.abs(Math.cos(c/180 * Math.PI) * MAX + MAX);   

 let div = document.createElement("DIV");
 div.style.height = 5 + 'px';
 div.style.width = value;
 div.classList.add("bar");

 if (value > MAX * EXCEED) {
  div.classList.add("exceed");
 
 }
 div.innerHTML = value;

 chart.appendChild(div);
}
</script>

   <script src="chart2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The outcome is supposed to look similar to this: [expected outcome]

[image]

Comment: You have a broken script, try to remove `and variables`. I also see the reference to `chart2` it is not related to this one right? or is that the “external jus file” you mentioned?

Comment: What does it look like now?  Also, are there any errors in your browser console?  There is probably an error because your script starts with "and variables", a syntax error.

Comment: First I think instead of setting the width, you should set the height, (otherwise it would be like you turned the example graph 90deg clockwise), second since you add the value as `innerHTML` it is normal to expect values being displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `display` of `#chart` to `flex` and you align the children of it the `flex-end` and you swap the height and width in JS, AND most importantly don't forget the `px` at the end of `value`!

If you want to have the value only on hover, then you should not put it directly as `innerHTML` but a child element with some css hover effect, or as a `data-*` attribute and use JS to do the trick. Also in your original code you didn’t include any axises so I didn’t include in my answer.

HTML:

```html
<div id=“chart”></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#chart {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.bar {
  background: green;
}
.exceed {
  background: blueviolet;
}
```

JS:

```js
 // and variables

const DPOINTS = 400;
const MAX = 300;
const EXCEED = 0.8;
let c;
let value;

let chart = document.getElementById("chart");

for (let c =0; c <= DPOINTS; c++){

 value = Math.abs(Math.cos(c/180 * Math.PI) * MAX + MAX);   

 let div = document.createElement("DIV");
 div.style.height = value + 'px';
 div.style.width = 5 + 'px';
 div.classList.add("bar");

 if (value > MAX * EXCEED) {
  div.classList.add("exceed");
 
 }
 div.innerHTML = value;

 chart.appendChild(div);
}
```

Bonus:
if you want to have value shown on hover (you can change the code for `onClick`), Add this css:

```css
#chart div span {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
#chart div:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

and change the `div.innerHTML = value;` in script to `div.innerHTML = '<span>' + value + '</span>';`.

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/jimmymcheung/pen/YzOYoRd)

p.s. Instead of `flex` you could also use `grid`.